Extract numerics in string column pyspark
I have a dataset with one row like this :



ID
Text




1
abc edf V345667 iii abe V345778 abc 1234 ab 12 V17 abe



And I just want to extract all elements which start by 'V' + 6 numerics
To get this :



List




V345667


V345778



How can I do it please using pyspark ? Thanks
I tried this :
df = df.withColumn("test", F.regexp_extract('Text', '(R\\d{6})' , 1 ))

To extract all elements which start with V and with 6 numerics but it returns an empty column ...

You can use regexp_extract_all function with V[0-9]{6}
df
.selectExpr("""explode_outer(regexp_extract_all(text, 'V[0-9]{6}', 0)) as list """).show(false)

+-------+
|list   |
+-------+
|V345667|
|V345778|
+-------+


from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

data = [Row(Id=1, Text="abc edf V345667 iii abe V345778 abc 1234 ab 12 V17 abe")]
schema = StructType([
    StructField(name="Id", dataType=IntegerType()),
    StructField(name="Text", dataType=StringType())
])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=schema)
regex = r"(V\d{6})"

df_new = (
    df
    .withColumn("regex", f.lit(regex))
    .withColumn(
        "extractions", 
        f.explode(
            f.regexp_extract_all("Text", "regex")
        )
    )
    .select("extractions")
)

df_new.display()

